# Convert minutes ( string ) to ISO 8601 duration format

Tags: javascript

I always store my minutes in a plain string format saying "90" for 90 minutes. I want to convert this to ISO 8601 duration format for schema.org standard.

E.g "90" should be converted to PT1H30M

Comment: "PT90M" is valid according to ISO 8601, if that makes it simpler for you.

Comment: Do you want to do this in vanilla JavaScript or are you open to using libraries?

Comment: @vlaz vanilla/es6 or moment.js

Answer (score 10):

In case whatever is going to read the interval isn't happy with values like PT90M, you can do something like this:

```
function MinutesToDuration(s) {
    var days = Math.floor(s / 1440);
    s = s - days * 1440;
    var hours = Math.floor(s / 60);
    s = s - hours * 60;

    var dur = "PT";
    if (days > 0) {dur += days + "D"};
    if (hours > 0) {dur += hours + "H"};
    dur += s + "M"

    return dur;
}

console.log(MinutesToDuration("0"));
console.log(MinutesToDuration("10"));
console.log(MinutesToDuration("90"));
console.log(MinutesToDuration(1000));
console.log(MinutesToDuration(10000));
```

Outputs:

> PT0M
>   PT10M
>   PT1H30M
>   PT16H40M
>   PT6D22H40M